# Multiselect dropdown in html5 for windows phone 8 and windows 8

Tags: html, cordova

I want to use multiselect dropdown for windows phone 8 using HTML 5 and JQuery.

The below one(I have given as a example for reference) is working for Android and Blackberry with the native UI feel but not for windows phone 8.

```
 <select name="ddl" id="ddlP" multiple="multiple">

 <option value="P">P</option>
 <option value="Q">q</option>
 <option value="R">R</option>
 <option value="S">S</option>

 </select>
```

`

I don't want to use JQuery mobile multiple select drop down.

Any idea how can I use the above one for windows phone 8?

Thanks in Advance.